# Understanding BackgroundService and CancellationToken

Tags: c#, service, background-service, cancellation-token, cancellationtokensource

I'm quite new to this. There is a lot of information around, and I'm a bit confused. I would like to verify that I understood correctly and appreciate any help. I will number each of my questions in (i) so it would be easier to answer.

I have a BackgroundService with ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) and StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken).

I assume both methods will get the same token when the service is run. (1) Is this true?

If I understand correctly, I'm supposed to use the cancellationToken in ExecuteAsync to do something as long as cancellationToken is not marked for cancellation.
ExecuteAsync has a while loop that runs iterations while cancellationToken is not cancelled. Each iteration awaits something to happen and may launch some async Tasks.

When I launch these tasks, I should give them a CancellationToken from a new CancellationTokenSource that is linked to cancellationToken so that (A) the task knows the stop both when the Service should be cancelled and when the task itself should be cancelled (but, in the latter case, without cancelling the Service itself); and (B) so that cancellationToken exhausted. (2) Are (A) and (B) correct?

Simply calling Cancel() on some CancellationTokenSource does not actually automatically cancels my Tasks or throws an exception. It is up to me to define this logic. (3) Is this true?

Which bring me to another question. Say that I discover insider some task that it was indeed marked for cancellation. What is the correct/expected behavior? Should I clean up the Task's resources and then use ThrowIfCancellationRequested() on the token that I have? (4) Is this true?

Lastly, how should I behave when the service itself is cancelled, i.e., when the main loop of ExecuteAsync discovers that its token is cancelled. (5) Should I immediately ThrowIfCancellationRequested? Should I first clean up resources and only then ThrowIfCancellationRequested? Or should I only call ThrowIfCancellationRequested as the last line of StopAsync?

Comment: Too many questions in one post. "I should give them a CancellationToken from a new CancellationTokenSource that is linked to cancellationToken" why not just use the existing token, why create a linked one? "It is up to me to define this logic" yes you need to pass it any method that accepts it, and/or call `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested`. "Should I first clean up resources" just use `using` everywhere and everything will be cleaned up automatically.

Comment: Sorry for too many questions. This is why I numbered them. Anyway, to answer: Wouldn't tasks be able to exhaust this token? Say I pass the same one to every task. Say I want only that task cancelled. Would that not mark the entire service to be cancelled as well?

Comment: Yeah obviously it's going to cancel everything. Depends what cancellation logic you are trying to achieve. No it won't exhaust anything, that's not how cancellation tokens work.

Comment: I have just tested running two tasks with a Token from the same CancellationTokenSource s. I ran the first task, used s.Cancel(), then tried to run the second task. This did not end well.
The reason I am asking about this specifically is that some of my tasks have a timeout and need to be cancelled independently of the service itself. Therefore, I don't want to mark the main CancellationToken for cancellation, rather, only that of the task that I want to cancel. From what I read (and tested), you can't reuse CancellationTokenSources.

Comment: No you're right if you need indpenedent cancellation then you would use a separate token source. But if you want overall cancellation of the whole service then you can use the same token

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have a BackgroundService with ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) and StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken).

Don't. You're mixing different levels of abstractions here.

Either use `BackgroundService` with `ExecuteAsync` *or* use `IHostedService` with `StartAsync` and `StopAsync`.

You probably just need `ExecuteAsync`. That's fine for most people.

> I assume both methods will get the same token when the service is run. (1) Is this true?

No. The cancellation tokens passed to `StartAsync`, `StopAsync` and `ExecuteAsync` are all different.

> If I understand correctly, I'm supposed to use the cancellationToken in ExecuteAsync to do something as long as cancellationToken is not marked for cancellation.

Yes. The cancellation token passed to `ExecuteAsync` is cancelled when it's time for the background service to stop.

> When I launch these tasks, I should give them a CancellationToken from a new CancellationTokenSource that is linked to cancellationToken

Do you ever need to cancel just a single task? If so, then yes. If not, then just pass the `cancellationToken` on directly.

> Simply calling Cancel() on some CancellationTokenSource does not actually automatically cancels my Tasks or throws an exception. It is up to me to define this logic. (3) Is this true?

Yes. Cancellation tokens must be observed. This is most commonly done by:

- Passing them down to any methods that take them. 99% of the time this is all you need to do.
- (Mainly for CPU-bound tasks) Periodically calling `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`.
- (Mainly for I/O-bound tasks) Registering a callback to perform the actual cancellation.

> Which bring me to another question. Say that I discover insider some task that it was indeed marked for cancellation. What is the correct/expected behavior? Should I clean up the Task's resources and then use ThrowIfCancellationRequested() on the token that I have? (4) Is this true?

Better: always have your resources defined in `using` statements. Then you can just `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` if you need to.

Again, 99% of the time, properly handling cancellation is just a matter of passing the token on down to some other method that already supports cancellation.

> Lastly, how should I behave when the service itself is cancelled, i.e., when the main loop of ExecuteAsync discovers that its token is cancelled. (5) Should I immediately ThrowIfCancellationRequested? Should I first clean up resources and only then ThrowIfCancellationRequested?

Handle it the same exact way: if your methods are cancellable, just pass it on down. Keep resources in `using` blocks. If you *need* to check (most don't), you can periodically call `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`.

Specifically:

> Each iteration awaits something to happen and may launch some async Tasks.

If your "awaits something to happen" is cancellable and your "launch some async Tasks" is cancellable, then just pass the cancellation token to both of these methods. No polling is necessary.

> Or should I only call ThrowIfCancellationRequested as the last line of StopAsync?

Don't use `StopAsync` if you're using `ExecuteAsync`.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that StopAsync belonged to another class. I will move my clean up logic to the end of ExecuteAsync. Indeed I need to sometimes cancel single tasks (specifically, those with timeout). I don't want these to cancel the service itself. By clean up I mean things like open connections (a task), although, now that I think about it, each connection should take care of itself once it is cancelled, so there's nothing to actually clean up.

Comment: Regarding ThrowIfCancellationRequested, if I understood correctly, this is my way (as a task) to signal my caller that I am cancelled. So I should indeed use it at the end of ExecuteAsync (and during any other Task that discovers it is being cancelled). I did not understand this, could you elaborate? "(Mainly for I/O-bound tasks) Registering a callback to perform the actual cancellation."

Comment: Regarding registration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/how-to-register-callbacks-for-cancellation-requests