# Why is my BackgroundService getting cancelled?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis-express, background-service, cancellation-token

I have a simple BackgroundService.

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        NotifyBase? notification = null;
        try
        {
            notification = await _queue.PullAsync(stoppingToken);
```

Where PullAsync is:

```
public class NotificationQueue : INotificationQueue
{
    private readonly Channel<NotifyBase> _queue;

    public NotificationQueue()
    {
        var opts = new BoundedChannelOptions(256) { FullMode = BoundedChannelFullMode.Wait };
        _queue = Channel.CreateBounded<NotifyBase>(opts);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public ValueTask<NotifyBase> PullAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return _queue.Reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
```

If I leave my web app alone, running under the Visual Studio debugger, then after about 10 minutes it throws a cancellation exception:

CancelledException Message: The operation was canceled.

With a call stack of:

```
   at System.Threading.Channels.AsyncOperation`1.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at LouisHowe.web.Services.BackgroundWorker.NotificationBackgroundService.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\Git\LouisHowe\LouisHowe.web\Services\BackgroundWorker\NotificationBackgroundService.cs:line 32
```

line 32 is `notification = await _queue.PullAsync(stoppingToken);`

What is going on here? [I've read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76582071/understanding-backgroundservice-and-cancellationtoken#:%7E:text=The%20cancellation%20token%20passed%20to,the%20background%20service%20to%20stop.) but while it talks about how to handle a cancel, it says nothing about why one would be triggered. I'm not cancelling it so I'm guessing the Visual Studio web server is. But why?

Comment: Web servers dislike long running tasks, so naturally they attempt to shut such down and reclaim the resources to handle incoming requests, https://halfblood.pro/unpleasant-facts-about-hangfire-632a3228ff8a If you do want to host long running threads, use a Windows service project please.

Comment: @LexLi A `BackgroundService` works real well for this in a lot of ways. An Azure Function would have to spin up/down every time I have a notification. Plus with this I can pass an object. Each time it runs it's very short. Is there a way I can have it keep this around for the life of the website? Or should I instantiate it every time I have more notifications? TIA

Comment: @DavidThielen Is the ~10 minutes constant, such that it won't ever go more than 10 minutes waiting for a notification without getting the error?  You may have a timeout somewhere that needs to be increased. Or can try turning off aborting thread on timeout (e.g. HttpContext.ThreadAbortOnTimeout Property or something similar depending on the underlying mechanism)

Comment: @publicwireless It's intermittent. Last 2 days it hasn't happened. I'm starting to think it was the Visual Studio IIS Express just deciding to shut down for some reason.